# import error rest_framework_httpsignature.authentication django rest frame work?

Tags: django, python-2.7

unable to import
`from rest_framework_httpsignature.authentication import SignatureAuthentication`
 in django 1.8v and python 2.7.6 ,it causeing importing error only to this class  SignatureAuthentication in vs studio , please help but i can able to import this class `rest_framework.authentication` using `djangorestframework==3.4.1` and `djangorestframework-httpsignature==0.2.1`

Comment: i think that is plynit extensions bug in vs editor

Answer (score 0):

You have somewhere in your code import from `rest_framework_httpsignature` which is not installed. It can be either set in your settings file as default authentication method for DRF or used somewhere in other default authentication method.

Comment: pip freeze showing all installed packages correctly,but i do not know why it is giving error